# Highcharts - Different Marker for Each Point of Area Plot

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to have a different marker for each point in my Highcharts area plot. I want the marker to be a wind barb png (shows the average wind direction and speed for a month), which is generated by the icons.php script on-demand. Here is what I have for my data block in my series:

```
series:[{
  data:[
    { x: 'January', y: 3717.71, marker:{ symbol: 'url(http://sample.ip.address/icons.php?type=barb&size=5&wspd=0&dir=219.38009049774)'}},
    { x: 'February', y: 3894.63, marker:{ symbol: 'url(http://sample.ip.address/icons.php?type=barb&size=5&wspd=0&dir=215.49200799201)'}},
    { x: 'March', y: 3628.49, marker:{ symbol: 'url(http://sample.ip.address/icons.php?type=barb&size=5&wspd=0&dir=193.80027422303)'}},
    { x: 'April', y: 2901.39, marker:{ symbol: 'url(http://sample.ip.address/icons.php?type=barb&size=5&wspd=0&dir=180.85734200743)'}},
    { x: 'May', y: 1756.8, marker:{ symbol: 'url(http://sample.ip.address/icons.php?type=barb&size=5&wspd=0&dir=171.72764227642)'}},
    { x: 'June', y: 1290.4, marker:{ symbol: 'url(http://sample.ip.address/icons.php?type=barb&size=5&wspd=0&dir=191.62322274882)'}},
    { x: 'July', y: 997.85, marker:{ symbol: 'url(http://sample.ip.address/icons.php?type=barb&size=5&wspd=0&dir=187.95557570263)'}},
    { x: 'August', y: 1035.04, marker:{ symbol: 'url(http://sample.ip.address/icons.php?type=barb&size=5&wspd=0&dir=180.14449541284)'}},
    { x: 'September', y: 1650.05, marker:{ symbol: 'url(http://sample.ip.address/icons.php?type=barb&size=5&wspd=0&dir=173.00561797753)'}},
    { x: 'October', y: 3154.83, marker:{ symbol: 'url(http://sample.ip.address/icons.php?type=barb&size=5&wspd=0&dir=188.1064690027)'}},
    { x: 'November', y: 3158.45, marker:{ symbol: 'url(http://sample.ip.address/icons.php?type=barb&size=5&wspd=0&dir=192.06400742115)'}},
    { x: 'December', y: 4075.64, marker:{ symbol: 'url(http://sample.ip.address/icons.php?type=barb&size=5&wspd=0&dir=215.48698384201)'}}]},
],
```

I've even tried this with the url being to a static image. I still get this same error in Firebug:

```
TypeError: f[a] is undefined
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would have to see how you do this in a jsfiddle or something, but I think your problem is the x value being a string and not an integer/decimal value. Are those x values supposed to be the categories along the x axis?

Comment: Yes, I have my xAxis categoies set for the months.

Comment: Will you put together a jsfiddle of your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Jordan.J.D -- You were right about the x values. I removed them and the images are now displaying. If you want to submit that as an answer, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the x value being a string and not an integer/decimal value. The x categories are set separately from the data. [Fiddle example from highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-symbols/)

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
```

is separate from

```
data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
            y: 26.5,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(http://www.YOURLINK.com/test.png)'
            }
        }, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
```

Comment: I appreciate this. This makes a lot more sense. It works perfectly now. Thank you very much.